# is it possible to run a 4k display using an eGPU on a mid 2012 MacBook Pro (non retina)

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, gpu, display

I'm interested in driving a 4k display by using an eGPU.

I've acquired a Sonnet Thunderbolt ePCI expansion chassis ([see here](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/legacyproducts/echoexpresschassis.html)) -- which will allow me to hook 1 double width ePCI card or two single width ePCI cards to my MacBook Pro via the Thunderbolt port.

Ideally I would like to hook an nVidea based GPU to this setup and then hook it to a 4k Monitor (so I can run CUDA stuff).

My primary need is screen real estate -- I do not need to be playing games -- but I do want a crisp display. I was thinking of a Samsung 40" 4K display [like this](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=9171854&CatId=8893).

Would appreciate if you answer addresses the following salient points:

1. Is this setup possible -- my research seem to indicate it is?
2. Is it stable -- does osx have bugs that make this setup non ideal.
3. Would nVidea based chip set be preferred (I also want to do CUDA stuff)
4. How do I find out if an nVidea card is supported by OSX
5. Any limitations on running the 4K display

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer for you but I'm curious why you would not just plug the display into your computer. Does it benefit to have it running straight from the eGPU?

Comment: @gary, the mid 2012 MBPs not retina versions don't support 4Ks -- Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i guess you solved your problem by now, but I still wanted to answer, since I recently looked into eGPU options myself.

If your sole aim is to run a 4K monitor (and your GPU doesn't support it), you could probably also get a USB graphics adapter. You find a selection [here](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters). This certainly is a much cheaper option, but probably too slow to watch videos, etc.

If you are into some more horsepower and want to place a powerful GPU into your Sonnet case, I suggest you take a look at the TechInferno forum. There is a growing community building their own eGPU solutions. If you look at their [table with implemented projects](http://forum.techinferno.com/diy-e-gpu-projects/6578-implementations-hub-tb-ec-mpcie.html#Thunderbolt), you will also find a number of solutions that used the Sonnet housing.

However, be warned. It is more complicated than just placing a graphics card into your PCIe case. Usually these cases do not provide enough power to run a GPU, and you will have to provide an additional power supply. Since this is all non-standard solutions, you may even have to solder on rather expensive hardware. So proceed at your own risk...